# Ember Data 404 when using store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

New to Ember.js, making a simple todo app to learn it a bit better.

In my `routes/todos.js` I have:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return [
      {
        title: 'walk the dog',
        completed: false,
      },
    ];
  },
});
```

However, when I change to:

```
export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('todo');
  },
});
```

I get the error:

```
ember-console.js:29 Error while processing route: todos Ember Data Request GET /todos returned a 404
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Where should the API request go to? findAll checks to see if there is data in the store, and if there is not, it makes a GET request

Comment: @handlebears ah okay, so I should set an initial value in the store if I'm not using an API?

Comment: Right, you can use createRecord to make some dummy data to go into the store, and you can use peekAll if you don’t want any API requests at all

Answer (score 1):

`findAll` will always make a request to the API server. If that doesn't exist or it isn't accessible, it will return a 404. Use `peekAll` if you just want to reference data in the Store without making an API request.

A 404 also will cause an error state to be thrown in the route and for the model to be rejected. Here is one way I've worked around that for APIs that DO throw 404s when there is no data (rather than a 200 with an empty array, for example):

```
return new EmberPromise(resolve => 
  this.get('store').findAll('todo').then(
    // resolves successfully whether the API call succeeds or fails
    todos => resolve(todos),
    err => {
      console.warn(err);
      resolve([]);
    }
  )
);
```